# Why is this creating a table of NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am analyzing test data and school budget data using pandas in jupyter notebook. This calculation is passing what appears to be a dataframe with a NaN in every field. Based on the calculation, it seems that it should be a list of schools with a percentage ov students passing BOTH reading and math. The `per_overall_passing` variable was calculated in the previous cell. However, it is producing a dataframe as well. Should this not be a series or a list? I've tried `.set_index` with  the `per_overall_passing` dataframe. This returns `'method' object is not subscriptable` error.

```
# Calculate the overall passing percentage.
per_overall_passing_percentage = per_overall_passing / per_school_counts * 100
per_overall_passing_percentage
```

Comment: `per_school_accounts` is probably zero.

Comment: Would that cause strings to become NaNs?

Comment: Dividing by zero is literally Not a Number.